# Numpy scipy 2d interpolation for linear piecewise data

Tags: python, scipy, linear-interpolation

I have the points:

```
points = np.array([[0, 105],[5000, 105],[0, 135],[5000, 135],[0, 165],[5000, 165]])
```

and values

```
values = np.array([[300, 380, 300, 390, 300, 400]]).transpose()
```

with the inputs I'm trying to interpolate for

```
xi = np.array([[2500, 105],[2500, 125],[2500, 135],[2500, 150],[2500, 165]])
```

with expected result for bilinear interpolation (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)

```
[340, 343.3333, 345, 347.5, 350]
```

My working for the second example using bilinear interpolation

```
x1=2500, y1=105 giving z1=340
x2=2500, y2=135 giving z2=345
Hence for x3=2500, y3=125 gives z3=343.3333
```

however, with

```
gd = griddata(points, values, xi, method='linear', rescale=True)
```

I'm getting the result

```
[340, 345, 345, 345, 350]
```

I must be missing something simple here, but have gotten nowhere trying multiple different approaches.

Comment: I don't understand what this interpolator is doing, but I made a contour plot to try to visualize what it's doing. It seems like it has a straight line along the Y axis at the point where you're interpolating. [plot](https://i.imgur.com/eXolRF3.png) See also the [scipy docs on LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`scipy.interpolate.interpn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html#scipy.interpolate.interpn) if you provide the data correctly. It expects you to provide the points as a list of individual x and y values (for the 2D case) that define the grid. The values are then defined in the format that corresponds to the grid, which is the result of `np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="ij")` for the 2D case. Be sure to provide x and y in strictly ascending or descending order or `interpn` will throw an error.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

x = np.array([0, 5000])
y = np.array([105, 135, 165])

# data corresponds to (x, y) given by np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="ij")
values = np.array([[300, 300, 300],
                   [380, 390, 400]])

xi = np.array([[2500, 105],
               [2500, 125],
               [2500, 135],
               [2500, 150],
               [2500, 165]])

interpolated = interpn((x, y), values, xi) # array([340., 343.33333333, 345., 347.5, 350.])
```

Here it is written as a function, though it doesn't have all the functionality necessary for general use, namely checking the inputs, ensuring proper datatypes, etc. I also haven't tested it beyond the given inputs, so I might have overlooked something.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

# moved one of the points and values to show it works with both unsorted
# x and y values
points = np.array([[0, 105],[5000, 105],[5000, 135],[0, 165],[5000, 165],[0, 135]])
values = np.array([[300, 380, 390, 300, 400, 300]]).T

xi = np.array([[2500, 105],[2500, 125],[2500, 135],[2500, 150],[2500, 165]])

def bilinear_interpolation(points, values, xi):
    p = points.copy()
    v = values.copy()

    # sorting the points to ensure ascending order
    ysorted = np.argsort(p[:,1])
    p = p[ysorted]
    v = v[ysorted]
    xsorted = np.argsort(p[:,0])
    p = p[xsorted]
    v = v[xsorted]
    
    x = np.unique(p[:,0])
    y = np.unique(p[:,1])
    v = v.reshape(x.size, y.size)

    return interpn((x, y), v, xi)

interpolated = bilinear_interpolation(points, values, xi)
```

Answer (score 0):

i run the code and get the same results as you.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

points = np.array([[0, 105], [5000, 105], [0, 135], [5000, 135], [0, 165], [5000, 165]])
values = np.array([[300, 380, 300, 390, 300, 400]]).transpose()
xi = np.array([[2500, 105],[2500, 125],[2500, 135],[2500, 150],[2500, 165]])

gd = griddata(points, values, xi, method='linear', rescale=True)
print(gd)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_trisurf(points[:,0], points[:,1], values.flatten(), cmap=cm.get_cmap('Blues'), linewidth=0.2)

# Customize the axes
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(3))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(3))
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(5))

plt.show()
```

the results are this:

```
[[340.]
 [345.]
 [345.]
 [345.]
 [350.]]
```

if i change from `linear` to `cubic` i get this:

```
[[340.46073832]
 [343.60340822]
 [345.00000255]
 [347.06944598]
 [349.53926443]]
```

which is much closer to what you expect...  so it looks like an interpolation method issue.

it looks like you are interpolating across this surface:

[image]

if you are able to show how you arrive at the expected result then it would be helpful...

Comment: Thanks! Have added some more detail behind my expected result

Answer (score 0):

This is a long one: You could write a function to accomplish the same:

```
import numpy as np
def interpolate(p, points, values):
    xpoint, ypoint = np.unique(points[:,0]), np.unique(points[:,1])
    z = values.reshape(ypoint.size, xpoint.size).T
    x, y = p[:,0], p[:,1]
    xind = np.searchsorted(xpoint, x)
    yind = np.searchsorted(ypoint, y)
    xind_min = np.maximum(xind - 1, 0)
    yind_min = np.maximum(yind - 1, 0)
    Q11 = z[xind_min, yind_min]
    Q12 = z[xind_min, yind]
    Q21 = z[xind, yind_min]
    Q22 = z[xind, yind]
    x1, x2 = xpoint[xind_min], xpoint[xind]
    y1, y2 = ypoint[yind_min], ypoint[yind]
    x_diff = np.where(x2 > x1, x2 - x1, 1)
    xy1 = ((x2 - x)*Q11 + (x - x1)*Q21) / x_diff
    xy2 = ((x2 - x)*Q12 + (x - x1)*Q22) / x_diff
    y_diff = np.where(y2 > y1, y2 - y1, 1)
    res = ((y2 - y) * xy1 + (y - y1) * xy2)/y_diff 
    equalX, equalY = x2 == x, y2 == y
    equalXY = equalX & equalY
    res[equalXY] =  z[xind[equalXY], yind[equalXY]]
    res[equalX & ~equalY] = z.mean(1)[xind[equalX & ~equalY]]
    res[~equalX & equalY] = z.mean(0)[yind[~equalX & equalY]]
    return res


points = np.array([[0, 105],[5000, 105],[0, 135],[5000, 135],[0, 165],[5000, 165]])
values = np.array([[300, 380, 300, 390, 300, 400]]).transpose()
xi = np.array([[2500, 105],[2500, 125],[2500, 135],[2500, 150],[2500, 165]])

interpolate(xi, points, values)
array([340.        , 343.33333333, 345.        , 347.5       ,
       350.        ])
```